# Hangman pygame game mechanic problems

Tags: python, pygame

The problem occurs in my game is that when I'm trying to insert word into the game, it doesn't show the letter, it should be showing me the letter when it is correct, if its wrong it should penalize me by adding one part of the hangman.

I did create the penalty function and the function that display the letter input by user when it is correct, help please !!

This is my code: http://pastebin.com/du98i88G

I think there might be problem in the `game()` function
`
    while not gameQuit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

```
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            if guess in secret:
                correct_letters = correct_letters + guess
                found = True

                for i in range(len(secret)):
                    if secret[i] not in correct_letters:
                        found = False
                        break

            if found == True:

                screen.fill(black)

                msgSize = pygame.font.Font("Hangman/ITCBLKAD.TTF", 80)
                msgText, msgText_Size = text_objects('Congratz!! You won!', msgSize)
                msgText_Size.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2)-70) 
                screen.blit(msgText, msgText_Size)

                msgSize1 = pygame.font.Font("Hangman/ITCBLKAD.TTF", 50)
                msgText1, msgText1_Size = text_objects('Play again?', msgSize1)
                msgText1_Size.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2)+30) 
                screen.blit(msgText1, msgText1_Size)

                buttonYes("Yes",350,295,80,40,black,grey)   
                buttonNo("No",550,295,80,40,black,grey) 

                pygame.display.flip()

            else:
                incorrect_letters = incorrect_letters + guess

                if len(incorrect_letters) == 7:

                    screen.fill(black)

                    display(incorrect_letters,correct_letters,secret)
                    msgSize = pygame.font.Font("Hangman/ITCBLKAD.TTF", 80)
                    msgText, msgText_Size = text_objects('You Lose! the word was: ' + secret, msgSize)
                    msgText_Size.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2)-70) 
                    screen.blit(msgText, msgText_Size)

                    msgSize1 = pygame.font.Font("Hangman/ITCBLKAD.TTF", 50)
                    msgText1, msgText1_Size = text_objects('Play again?', msgSize1)
                    msgText1_Size.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2)+30) 
                    screen.blit(msgText1, msgText1_Size)

                    buttonYes("Yes",350,295,80,40,black,grey)   
                    buttonNo("No",550,295,80,40,black,grey) 

                    pygame.display.flip()
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not updating your display after a wrong guess. Try moving the line

```
display(incorrect_letters,correct_letters,secret)
```

above the `if` block.

---

Another problem might arise from the use of the variable `found`. You check `if guess in secret` and in the next block you check the value of `found` which is defined only within the previous `if` block. Add `found = False` above the first `if` block to prevent that.

Comment: I've try that @Maximillian Peters, not wroking sadly

Comment: @DarkxRift: Have a look at the updated answer, if not try to trim down your example to a minimal working example, i.e. no local images and fonts.